# how to handling button click in tab fragment using RecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

currently i had come out a screen that using tab fragment and  RecyclerView like below. I want to know how i going to handle the button click that circle in red. Every time  i click, i have get the details of the product that i want to add into the cart. Since the screen that i come out is using RecyclerView , so i'm confusing how to get all the details of the product that i want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohzQP.png)

Adapter code

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView row_image;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;

    public ViewHolder(View v, Context c) {
        super(v);
        mContext = c;
        row_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);
    }


}

public CatalogPageAdapter(List<CatalogViewData> dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.catalog_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v,parent.getContext());
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final CatalogViewData fakePageVH = mDataset.get(i);
    String points = Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(fakePageVH.getDescription()));

    viewHolder.title.setText(fakePageVH.getTitle());
    viewHolder.description.setText(points);
    String var = fakePageVH.getImage();

    new getImage(var, viewHolder).execute();

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Title: " + fakePageVH.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public class getImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String imageUrl;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Bitmap downloadedBitmap;
    Bitmap scaled;

    public getImage(String url, ViewHolder h){
        imageUrl = url;
        holder = h;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            downloadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(downloadedBitmap, 150, 100, true);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "done";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        holder.row_image.setImageBitmap(scaled);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset == null ? 0 : mDataset.size();
}
```

}

Comment: try it before, it only link to cart Activity without the details i want

Answer (score 2):

I guess the green icon isn't an `ImageView` otherwise would be a silly question. Add an empty `ImageView`, place it exactly on your circle. Then add it into your viewholder and use `viewHolder.dummyImageView.setOnClickListener`.

*EDIT*

xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dummyImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

VievHolder:

```
public ViewHolder(View v, Context c) {
    super(v);
    dummyImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dummyImageView);
}
```

OnClickListener:

```
ImageView dummyImage;

viewHolder.dummyImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give some example? TQ

Comment: This to toast the message out it is?

Comment: Yes, it is just a sign to know that it is clicked.

Comment: can i clicked it to trigger add to cart action and link to database?

Comment: Yes replace "Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" line with your add to cart action.

Comment: Ok, then how can i get the detail that i want to put in database?

Comment: That's a different question from this. You can get details from your adapter class.  getView(position, view, viewGroup) gives you detail of item at "position". You should ask a new question for this or make some search on google.